# How to use parameters from commandline inside a main function in C++ using SET-Command

Tags: c++, function, cmd, parameters

Sorry, I have never really worked with Commandline parameters. Maybe this is a stupid question:

I have a simple file test.cpp with a main function. I now want to start this program from the Commandline after having set the variable var with a value from the Commandline. (How) Can I do this?

test.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int var;  // do I need to declare this variable here?

  if (var == 123)
      puts(" var=123 !!");      
}
```

In the Commandline can I type something like that:

- set /A var=123
- test

And main would print  "var=123 !!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` defines an environment variable. That's a variable that exists in the environment of your application, i.e. outside your application. You can't use that to set variables inside your program.

You can however access the environment using [std::getenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(void) {
    const char* env_abc = std::getenv("ABC");
    if (env_abc)
    {
        int abc = std::atoi(env_abc);
        std::cout << abc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean running from command line something like "test 123",
then the argv[] argument contains your command line, when argv[0] is the name of the process, and argv[1] and so on are your command line arguments represented as strings

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int var = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (var == 123)
        puts(" var=123 !!");      
}
```

Comment: Just make sure to validate the value of `argc` before accessing any `argv` elements so you don't go out of bounds.  `argc` gives you the number of strings that are in `argv`.